# Scan Query 2 Arguments

Tags: go

i have 2 query

```
 selDB, err := db.Query(`SELECT grup_master_code.nama_group FROM grup_master_code
                        SELECT master_code.item_code FROM master_code`)
```

and when i scan that query, i have error

```
sql: expected 1 destination arguments in Scan, not 2
```

Code Scan

```
var nama_grup, item_code string
err = selDB.Scan(&nama_grup, &item_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION will continue the rows, not create a 2nd column! 
For UNION the fields must be the same type and UNION ALL will include duplicate rows.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

First you need to check the data you are querying.